Github not getting triggered when the PR's are closed but not merged
The workflow has to delete the branches with pattern ID- or id- as prefix for closed pull request. Below is the workflow file. But no action is triggered.
name: Delete branch when PR not merged

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: write

# only trigger on pull request closed events
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed ]

jobs:
  run_only_when_pr_not_merged:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action =='closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged == false
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch name
        shell: bash
        run: echo "branch=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        id: extract_branch
          
      - name: Delete branch
        uses: dawidd6/action-delete-branch@v3
        if: contains(steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch, 'ID-') || contains(steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch, 'id-') 
        with:
          github_token: ${{github.token}}
          branches: ${{ github.head_ref }}

Tried different if conditions in job and on condition in workflow

One reason this could happen is the workflow is not present on the PR branch.
Create a new branch off master/main with this workflow and try again.
This workflow is triggered for me when I create a new branch, commit a change, create a PR and close it without merging
name: pr-closed

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed ]

jobs:
  show:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ github.head_ref }} $GITHUB_REF


This worked. Thank you.
